# Issue of computing standard deviation of numpy.ndarray using custom method

Tags: python, numpy

So I have tried to make my own implementation of computing the standard deviation of a matrix. To check that it was correct, I implemented as simpler version that only takes a single column/row and computes its standard deviation.

I tried passing both of these a single-column numpy.ndarray to see that they give the same result, but they do not. I have really scratched my head about this but I cannot figure out why they are giving different results.

```py
class General_Methods:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    """
    This function gets the standard deviation for each column in the passed array. Uses the corrected formula for standard deviation (divides by n-1 instead of n, n being the number of elements)

    Parameters:
        matrix - an array-like object of values to get the standard deviation of
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get_sd(matrix : np.ndarray):
        rows, cols = matrix.shape
        mu = matrix.mean(axis=0)
        mtx_sub_mu = np.subtract(matrix, mu)
        vectors = np.split(mtx_sub_mu, mtx_sub_mu.shape[-1], axis=-1)
        sds = np.zeros((1, len(vectors)))
        for i, vector in enumerate(vectors):
            # Result differs after the line of code below
            s_square = np.divide(np.square(vector).sum(), vector.size - 1)
            sds[0, i] = np.sqrt(s_square)
        return sds

    """
    Simple method to get standard deviation on a single column array, used for comparison with the more complicated version above.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def sd(vector : np.ndarray):
        mu = vector.mean()
        v_sub_mu = np.subtract(vector, mu)
        # Result differs after the line of code below
        s_square = np.divide(np.square(vector).sum(), vector.size - 1)
        return np.sqrt(s_square)
```

I checked that up until the variable `s_square` is calculated both methods are giving identical results, but the calculation for `s_square` gives different results, and I can't understand why as from what I can tell that are literally the same line of code? Unless I'm being the dumbest man.

Any help in puzzling this out would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In your static method for calculation the stdev of one colum sd you mixed up variables. You squared the values in the input vector and not v_sub_mu. It should read: `s_square = np.divide(np.square(v_sub_mu).sum(), vector.size - 1)`

Comment: Oh, thank you. That was silly.